# React Native Structure an Object from Available Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using a library that has a specific object structure and it looks like this:

```
const libraryTemplateData = [
    {
        eventContainerStyle: {
            style: {
                opacity: 1,
            },
        },
        title: {
            content: "Title Item #1",
        },
        description: {
            content: "Description Item #2",
        },
        time: {
            content: "Time Item #2",
            style: { opacity: 1 },
        },
        icon: {
            style: {
                opacity: 1,
            },
        },
    },
    {
        title: {
            content: "Title Item #2",
        },
        description: {
            content: "Description Item #2",
        },
        time: {
            content: "Time Item #2",
        },
    },
    {
        title: {
            content: "Title Item #3",
        },
        description: {
            content: "Description #3",
        },
        time: {
            content: "Time Item #3",
        },
    },
```

and so on..

I also have a data that I receive from API call (can't restructure it on a DB level to match the `libraryTemplateData`):

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "ID": "59732379",
        "TIME": "16:00",
        "TITLE": "Item Title #1",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Description Item #1"
    },
    {
        "ID": "59732361",
        "TIME": "18:00",
        "TITLE": "Title Item #2",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Description Item #2"
    }
],
"result": 0,
"resultdescription": "OK"
```

}

and so on..

How to map `data` to the type of object in `libraryTemplateData`? I also need to change the properties in data[0] as you can see in `libraryTemplateData[0]`. The opacity has to be set to achieve the "light up" effect. All elements after `data[0]` will be `opacity:0` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use a simple `map` to achieve it:

```js
const libraryTemplateData = data.map((item, index) => ({
  eventContainerStyle: {
    style: {
      opacity: index === 0 ? 1 : 0,
    },
  },
  title: {
    content: item.TITLE,
  },
  description: {
    content: item.DESCRIPTION,
  },
  time: {
    content: item.TIME,
    style: {
      opacity: index === 0 ? 1 : 0,
    },
  },
  icon: {
    style: {
      opacity: index === 0 ? 1 : 0,
    },
  },
}));
```

Comment: I was just about to edit the question of how I did it, but you were faster... :) I used a function and put a const inside of it and it didn't quite work, but still showed the items. Your solution is perfect, thank you!